# What is my salary expectation in Germany with Remuneration group 11 TV-H, if I have master degree?

Tags: germany, salary

I did master in Germany. One of the public sector company offers me a job with "Remuneration group(entgeltgruppe) 11 TV-H".

"*Remuneration group 11 TV-H*" is basically for *Bachelor*. My question is, my salary belongs to which Stage of Remuneration group 11 TV-H.

They will add 2 years of experience from my master degree or not. If they add then my salary belongs to stage 3, otherwise, stage 1.

[Salary group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evMkO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "stage of remuneration" (Stufe, table column) increases after having worked N years in your current Stufe, i.e., you go to Stufe 2 after working 1 year in Stufe 1, then you go to Stufe 3 after two **additional** years in Stufe 2, and so on.

This only counts paid work done in public service (öffentlicher Dienst). It is not there to reward "having experience in the field" but to reward "staying for a long time in the job". Unless you had a full-time TV-H11 job for more than a year during your Master studies (which is not allowed), experience as a student will not count towards starting at a higher Stufe.

Comment: I did an **Internship** ( 3 months full time), **working student** (9 months for 21 hours / week) and **master thesis** (6 months full time) in another company. Would be this experience evaluated?

Comment: Work in another company does not count. Working student and internship have reduced salary and will also not count. Only full-time, full-salary TV-H E11 in the public service would count. I also have to say that people with a Master's degree usually get Entgeltgruppe 13 or more. I do not know your field or situation, but you might want to check out other job options before accepting this one...